# Swift Package Manager - how to link remote .zip that contains multiple binaries inside?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, binaries, xcframework

I would need to create a package from the binaries provided by third-party company - they support CocoaPods, but we use the SPM, so we decided to create the package ourselves from the binaries they provide - *ios-jumio-mobile-sdk-4.0.0.zip* file.

So I created the package and added the dependencies to remote .zip file in *Package.swift*:

```
.binaryTarget(name: "Jumio",
              url: "https://mobile-sdk.jumio.com/com/jumio/ios/jumio-mobile-sdk/4.0.0/ios-jumio-mobile-sdk-4.0.0.zip",
              checksum: "f9167e0f483542da2dde32791d8229246abd520141af1005acfd78a86f926d3d")
```

The *ios-jumio-mobile-sdk-4.0.0.zip* structure looks like that:

```
ios-jumio-mobile-sdk-4.0.0/
├─ Jumio/
│  ├─ Jumio.xcframework
├─ SocketIO.framework/
├─ iProov/
│  ├─ iProov.xcframework
```

Unfortunately when I try to build the package, Xcode throws an error:

*"unknown binary artifact file extension 'unknown'"*

Do you know if it is possible to link a remote .zip with multiple binaries inside?